# Java float to string conversion with trailing zeros

Tags: java, string, floating-point

I have a requirement where I am getting a float value in java like the one below

```
1.1
1.10
10.10
```

when I convert this to string, I want it to be in the same way as

```
"1.1"
"1.10"
"10.10"
```

however, when I use the following method,

```
float fa = 25.50f;//Float.parseFloat("25.5");
        String s = Float.toString(fa);
        System.out.println(s); // i want the output to be 25.50, but it gives me 25.5
```

the result turns out to be the following

```
"1.1"
"1.1"
"10.1"
```

can somebody advise me how to get `1.10` as `"1.10"` with the zero in java

Comment: Use BigDecimal because that keeps the scale. 10.1 and 10.10 are effectively the same value so if you're using float or double there's no information about that trailing zero.

Comment: Btw, "I use the following method" - which method?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: There's no difference between `1.1` and `1.10`.

Comment: @Kitis Does the float value come from String ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to store the whole number, why don't you just use a String?

I guess if you are getting "1.10" from somewhere, you are getting it as a String (or you would be getting just a "1.1").

Answer (score 1):

There isn't (necessarily) a float value like 10.10f. There might be, but thing is: when you write down a float literal, you shouldn't expect that it **really** looks like the value you put down.

Only when representing numbers as **strings** you can uphold such requirements regarding formatting.

In other words, you probably should read [this](https://computingat40s.wordpress.com/java-float-and-double-primitive-types-are-evil-dont-use-them/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

How it is printed is determined by how you format a number, the `float` is just a value, and it's actual representation is binary, not decimal.

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", 25.5f); // 25.50
```

I highly recommend using `double` which is simpler to use, and half a trillion times more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If your float value comes from String I suggest below solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String floatValue = "25.20";
    String[] splittedFloat = floatValue.split("[.]"); 
    int numberOfDecimalPlaces = splittedFloat[1].length();

    float value = Float.valueOf(floatValue);
    System.out.printf("%." + numberOfDecimalPlaces + "f\n", value);


}
```

First you declare your value as String. Then split it with "dot" and check the length of decimal places. Then you parse it into your float value and you do whatever you want with this value. And finally you cat print it with format like previous because you have number of decimal places of this float value.

The output of this code is:

```
25.20
```

There is no way to hold 25.20 value in float because the actual value is 25.2 and that 0 is formatting.